# How to open static html file in asp.net mvc without controller & view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some HTML files that are stored in a folder and I want to open these HTML files.

I added the below code in the `route.config` file:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{about.html}",
defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Index", id = 
UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Now this about.html url has created and on about controller Index Action I have called view. so it is working but I am open directly file from folder then it is not opened.

I am facing the error

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   Internal Server Error

Most likely causes are:

```
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.
```

I want the path to be [example.com/Folder/test.html](http://example.com/Folder/test.html).

Comment: As far as I know, unless the file is in the Views folder, you do not require to tweak your web.config. So for example, if you have a folder name "StaticFiles" then a file "index.html" you should be able to access it via http://yourapp/StaticFiles/index.html

Comment: can you share the code how you are calling the html file.

Comment: By default, routes.**IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");** is not even needed. Asp.Net MVC is capable of hosting static html by default. No configuration needed. Your problem must be located somewhere else. I would advise you to look at your server logs and handle all the exceptions to be certain of what is exactly your problem. Look at https://stackify.com/aspnet-mvc-error-handling/ to see how to handle errors in ASP.Net MVC

Answer (score 0):

I have dynamic pages for that I have created Route is as below

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Article",
            url: "article/{name}.html",
            defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I added the above route for .html extension then above route not worked so I changed configuration in web.config. after that it has started for working. but when I call to static html file it was showing me error.

so for that I crated below code in my controller and finally I received a solution

```
public ActionResult Index(string page)
    {
        var pageRoute = "~/uploads/" + page + ".html";
        var staticPageToRender = new FilePathResult(pageRoute, "text/html");
        return staticPageToRender;
    }
```